# Uniqueness to Schauder fixed-point theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, compact-operators, monotone-functions

Using Schauder fixed-point theorem, existence of a fixed-point can be proven. I am wondering how to prove the uniqueness of a fixed point under some additional conditions. For example, consider the operator $R$ on a suitable convex function space (e.g. $C(0,T;\mathbb{H})$)

$$(Ru)(t)=K(t)u_0+\int_0^tK(t-s)F(u(s))ds$$

where

- $F(\cdot)$ is a locally-Lipschitz nonlinear operator on $\mathbb{H}$, a Hilbert space.
- $K(t)$ is a uniformly continuous semi-group of compact linear operators on $\mathbb{H}$ (i.e. $\|K(t)\|$ is continuous for $t>0$ and $K(t)$ is compact for every $t$).
- $u_0\in \mathbb{H}$ is fixed.

Now, Schauder fixed-point theorem guarantees the existence of a fixed-point for $R$; but how is it going to be unique?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious way of assuming there are two fixed points?

Comment: Yes, that's an standard way to proof a uniqueness. But, I can't go further.

Comment: There are some problems in your definition of $R$. If $u$ is a function, let's say $u\in C^0(I)$, then $(R u )(t)\in \mathbb{R}$. But $K(t):C^0(I) \to C^0(I)$  then $K(t)\cdot u_0$ is a function so you cannot write $R u(t) = K(t) u_0 + something$. Also I wonder how is defined $F$. If it is $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ you cannot compute $K(t-s) F(u(s))$ in the integral (since $K(t)$ takes functions in input), also if $F$ is defined over a  function space it makes no sense to write   $K(t-s) F(u(s))$ in the integral.

Comment: @WarlockOfFiretopMountain
Thanks for your comment, I rephrased the set of assumptions.  Now, you can see the underlying space are $\mathbb{H}$-valued continuous functions. Think of two-variable functions $u(x,t)$, continuous with respect to $t$ and for every $t$, we have $u(x,\cdot)\in \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-060-01/S0002-9939-1976-0423137-6/S0002-9939-1976-0423137-6.pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering uniqueness, the semigroup $\{K(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ doesn't have to be compact and it is enough that $\mathbb{H}$ is a Banach space.

Assume there are two fixed-points $u_1$ and $u_2\in C([0,T],\mathbb{H})$ of the operator $R$. There is the Lipschitz constant $L>0$ and $\rho>0$ such that 
$$ 
u,v \in B(u_0,\rho) \Rightarrow \|F(u)-F(v)\|\leq L\|u-v\|.
$$
Since $u_1(0)=u_0=u_2(0)$ and $u_1$, $u_2$ are (uniformly) continuous, there is $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
u_1(s),\; u_2(s)\in B(u_0,\rho) \quad\text{for every }s\in[0,\delta].
$$
Moreover, we have a standard estimate
$$
\|K(t)\|\leq M e^{\omega t},\quad\text{for every }t\geq 0
$$
for some $M\geq 1$ and $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$.
Therefore, for $t\in[0,\delta]$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|u_1(t)-u_2(t)\|&=\left\|\int_0^t K(t-s)[F(u_1(s))-F(u_2(s))] ds\right\|\\
&\leq M\int_0^t e^{\omega (t-s)}\|F(u_1(s))-F(u_2(s))\|ds\\
&\leq M\int_0^te^{\omega (t-s)}L\|u_1(s)-u_2(s)\|ds.
\end{aligned}
$$
We use Gronwall lemma and get $\|u_1(t)-u_2(t)\|=0$ for $t\in[0,\delta]$.

Now, we argue as above inductively. 
We can also cover the compact set $u_1([0,T])$ by finite number of open neighbourhoods where $F$ is Lipschitz. Then we take the greatest Lipschitz constant and proceed as above.

Comment: It seems the uniform continuity of the linear semigroup is not needed, either, right?